# Azure Worker Role and Nunit

Tags: azure, nunit, resharper

I have some Azure worker roles that I'd like to unit test.
I choose NUnit for this and I have Resharper on my VS2013

Everytime I debug the tests it seem to initialise stuff and then it stops. I never go to the debug mode.

Looking at the output window I find this:

```
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100 : Role environment . INITIALIZING
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100 : Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED. HResult=-2147024894
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024894
```

Not sure if this is the problem but I'm kinda stuck here...

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

`-2147024894` is file not found. All files available? Use `procmon` to see which files are being read and which ones are not being found.